# jld2fileをpythonで読み込めない

Tags: python, python3

ファイルが開くところまでは確認済です。このエラーの対処法を教えてください。お願いします。

```
OSError: Can't read data (can't open directory: /usr/local/hdf5/lib/plugin)
```

```
import h5py

# JLDファイルを開く
with h5py.File('/Users/kobayashitaku/Desktop/julia_python/myvorticiescount/df_40K_120mW_m40mV.jld2', 'r') as file:
    
    df = file["process/δf"][:]
    
# 読み込んだデータを表示する
print(df)
```

Comment: ここが参考になるかも https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301346/
h5pyファイルを開くために必要なプラグインが見つからない, ようです